# DontGoThroughThings and OnCollisionEnter

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm using the [DontGoThroughThings](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=DontGoThroughThings) script to fix collisions of really fast moving objects. What I want to do is remove the hit triangle within a sphere when my fast moving object hits. It works for really slow objects, however, when I shoot a fast object, the object calls the OnCollisionEnter but I cannot find the triangle that it hit and the fast moving object sticks onto the collided item. I'm thinking it's because the DontGoThroughThings sets the object position to the collided object and the direction is lost, so my ray cannot find the proper triangle.

[image]

Here's the code on my sphere:

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collisionInfo)
{
    int[] triangles = mesh.triangles;

    for (var i = 0; i < collisionInfo.contacts.Length; i++)
    {
        RaycastHit hit;
        colliderRay.Raycast(new Ray(collisionInfo.contacts[i].point, collisionInfo.contacts[i].normal), out hit, 10.0f);

        if (hit.collider != null && hit.triangleIndex != -1)
        {
            triangles = removeTriangle(hit.triangleIndex, triangles);
        }
    }

    mesh.triangles = triangles;
    meshCollider.sharedMesh = mesh;
}

private int[] removeTriangle(int triangle, int[] tris)
{
    for (var i = triangle * 3; i < tris.Length - 3; ++i)
    {
        if (tris[i] == -1) break;
        tris[i] = tris[i + 3];
    }
    return tris;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem. I needed to move the point a few units back and then cast the raycast. So it would look like:

```
    colliderRay.Raycast(new Ray(collisionInfo.contacts[i].point - (collisionInfo.contacts[i].normal.normalized), collisionInfo.contacts[i].normal), out hit, 10.0f);
```